# How can I generate an ABI out of a wasm?

Tags: smart-contract, abi, wasm

Currently I've written a rust program to print "5" and converted the same into wasm using the the rust tool (target add wasm32-unknown-unknown). I want this wasm to be executed on the local blockchain as a basic contract. I've create account and trying to execute the contract specifying the .wast file. (I manually converted wasm to wast) but I have not Idea how can I create ABI (application binary interface) required by EOSIO to run the contract on the blockchain. Please help.

Here is the exact code: 
rustup install nightly
rustup default nightly
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
cargo install -f cargo-web

switch to EOS directory.

eos/programs/

Create new Cargo Project:

```
$ cargo new eos
```

Modify the Cargo.toml contents with the following:

```
[package]
name = "eos"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["manish@knoldus.com"]
[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
[dependencies]
```

Create another file src/lib.rs and put the following content:

---

```
#![feature(panic_implementation)]
#![no_std]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

extern "C" {
    fn printi(c: u64);
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn init() {
    unsafe { printi(5); }
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn apply(_: u64, _: u64) {}
#[panic_implementation]
fn panic(pi: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
       loop{}
}
```

---

Once the source is ready, do: 
cargo +nightly build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release

Also, I've followed this blog[enter link description here](https://www.sales4k.com/blockchain/eos-contracts-rust-no-cpp/) for rust reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no recommended tools for generating ABI automatically. However, there's [an article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/how-to-write-an-abi) in the documentation about how to write an ABI file yourself.

From the article:

> As of v1.2.0, the eosio.wasmsdk was decoupled from the core
>   repository. This change has introduced an eosiocpp regression where
>   the legacy eosio-abigen is no longer bundled with eosio-cpp. Until a
>   new ABI generator is introduced, you will need to hand-write your ABI
>   files.